# What event is triggered whenever the app is dragged back into the current window?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I'm struggling with the activation lifecycle for my app. I just want to save the state for the current page whenever the app is hidden or whenever the user navigates to a different page. Conversely, I want to restore the state whenever the user launches my app or navigates back to that page.

In the following case, I detect that the app was made hidden so I store the page's state, but I never get notified that the app was reactivated so I can restore the state:

(on surface)

```
  1. launch app
  2. press start
  3. drag app from left edge of screen and drop it back into focus
```

I was hoping the Resuming event would do it, but no. Which event should I use?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.resuming.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the whole app, check [Window.Activated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.activated.aspx), for individual pages you can use [Page.OnNavigatedFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedfrom.aspx) / [Page.OnNavigatedTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedto.aspx).

Comment: Thanks but neither of these events are triggered in the above scenario, that is why I am asking this question.

Comment: Actually sorry you are right... I was doing something stupid and unregistering for the Activated event after being deactivated :(